# AddGeometryColumn not creating column on new Spatialite database

Tags: c#, spatialite, sqlite

I'm creating a new Spatialite database using c# and .net through the following code:

```
using var connection = new SqliteConnection($"Data Source={Path.Combine(outputDirectory, "data.db")}");
connection.Open();

try
{
    connection.EnableExtensions();

    using var command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "SELECT load_extension('mod_spatialite');";
    command.ExecuteScalar();

    //create the required tables
    using var tableCreateCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
    tableCreateCommand.CommandText =
                        "SELECT InitSpatialMetaData();" +
                        "CREATE TABLE Places (Id TEXT PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE NOT NULL, Name TEXT, Description TEXT, TypeId INTEGER, TotalReviews INTEGER, AverageRating INTEGER) WITHOUT ROWID;";
    tableCreateCommand.ExecuteScalar();

    //attach the geometry column
    using var geomAttachCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
    geomAttachCommand.CommandText = 
                        "SELECT AddGeometryColumn('Places', 'Location', 4326, 'POINT', 'XY');" +
                        "SELECT CreateSpatialIndex('Places', 'Location');";
    geomAttachCommand.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

That creates the database and table correctly, but the `Location` column is never created. If I open the newly created database using spatialite_gui and then execute `SELECT AddGeometryColumn('Places', 'Location', 4326, 'POINT', 'XY');` again. It returns a 0 but once again, no column is created.

According [to the docs](https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-5.0.1.html) `the return type is Integer, with a return value of 1 for TRUE or 0 for FALSE` but they don't go into anymore details with regards to what the 0 actually means?

Is there anything that I'm missing that would cause the `AddGeometryColumn` function to fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that SpatiaLite requires rowids. Remove  `WITHOUT ROWID` and your commands will work. However, I am not sure if SpatiaLite works well if the primary key is of TEXT type. I would recommend to use INTEGER-AUTOINCREMENT PK as below, but if you definitely want to use TEXT PK then it would be good to test that all that you want to do really work correctly.

```
CREATE TABLE Places3(Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
Name TEXT, Description TEXT, TypeId INTEGER, TotalReviews INTEGER, AverageRating INTEGER);
```

Comment: Okay yeah that was it, I removed `WITHOUT ROWID` and the column gets created correctly, thanks!